# Irregular shaped buttons on the UI of an application.Android

Tags: android, xml, button, imageview

I am in the process of creating an app which requires irregular shaped buttons. I know that i can use image buttons and have the irregular shapes set as the images but no matter what is the shape of the image, it always occupies a rectangular area on the screen.
Is it possible to have the button occupy the exact shape of the image alone?
Do i need to create a custom control or layout for doing this or is there any other valid approach?
If i need to create a custom layout then how do i ensure that the space enclosed by all the buttons that i have placed on the layout is always circular or elliptic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override onDraw method in any view you need to shape, see this code to round ImageView

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation") @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = null;

        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
            Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
            canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        }

        if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
            b = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            ((LayerDrawable) drawable).setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
            ((LayerDrawable) drawable).draw( new Canvas(b));

        }

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;
        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
        else
            sbmp = bmp;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight(),
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xffa19774;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
                sbmp.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f, sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

}
```